# Убрать валидацию с некоторых полей

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Есть интернет-магазин. На определенной странице в форме с некоторых полей нужно убрать валидацию. Подскажите как?

Валидатор: https://github.com/atetlaw/Really-Easy-Field-Validation

Сайт и страница, на которой нужно убрать: http://www.policemart.com/contact-us

Изначально всем полям был присвоен сласс "required-entry". Его убрал где надо. Если никакие поля не заполнять и нажать кнопку, то появятся ошибки только там где остался этот класс, но если эти поля заполнить и опять нажать кнопку, то ошибки появятся в остальных полях.

Comment: Проблема еще актуальна? Сейчас попробовал, форма отправилась с 3-я заполненными полями.

Comment: Не актуально, решил проблему, спасибо